# How to set up a button to invert two textFields

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I'm an absolute beginner, and I need to have a button to invert two text fields:
text1 <—> text2

```
- (IBAction)swapText {
    name.text = surname.text;
    surname.text = name.text;
}
```

I know that I have to retain the values and then release them, but I'm not sure how to write it.

Comment: We were all beginners and we are still beginners in one subject or another...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple: the only text / NSString you have to retain is the one that will stop being hold by the `UITextField` itself, namely the `name.text` that you will replace by `surname.text`.

```
- (IBAction)swapText {
  NSString* temp = [name.text retain];
  name.text = surname.text;
  surname.text = temp;
  [temp release];
}
```

Comment: Wow, Im glad to have so much answers, Im  extremely thankful to evryone, Im going to take some time to study all your answers. At first view the last answer seems the good one for me.

Comment: Great :) If this solution works for you, don't forget to mark your answer as resolved by ticking the green checkmark next to the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

The only objects you need to take care of would be alloc/deallocating the UITextFields. Assuming your UITextfields are ivars (declared in your header file) you can use the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  CGRect b = [[self view] bounds];

  _txt1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(b)-100, 50, 200, 29)];
  [_txt1 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
  [[self view] addSubview:_txt1];

  _txt2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(b)-100, 100, 200, 29)];
  [_txt2 setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
  [[self view] addSubview:_txt2];

  UIButton* btnSwap = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [btnSwap setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(b)-75, 150, 150, 44)];
  [btnSwap setTitle:@"Swap Text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [btnSwap addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedSwapButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [[self view] addSubview:btnSwap];
}

- (void)tappedSwapButton
{
  NSString* text1 = [_txt1 text];
  NSString* text2 = [_txt2 text];

  [_txt2 setText:text1];
  [_txt1 setText:text2];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
  [_txt1 release];
  [_txt2 release];

  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Notice the UIButton is using the method [UIButton buttonWithType:]. This is a autoreleased object as opposed to the UITextFields using and alloc/init method. Hence why we don't dealloc the UIButton in the dealloc method

Comment: The code in `tappedSwapButton` will crash as the instance variables `text1` and `text2` won't retain the strings and as you do `[_txt2 setText:text1]`, the string that was previously in txt2 (and that you point to using `text2` variable) won't be retained by anyone, and will potentially be removed from memory (leaving you with `text2` being a dandling pointer -- pointing to memory that has been deleted since). This may sometimes work if you're lucky but, if the memory has been erased in the meantime it will crash directly. You have to retain values during the swapping operation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code given, your text in the first textfield will be lost.  The easiest way to fix that is to declare a temp NSString object that will hold the string that is contained in name.text:

```
- (IBAction)swapText{

  // create a temp string to hold the contents of name.text
  NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithString: name.text];

  name.text = surname.text;
  surname.text = tempString;
}
```

Since you are using dot notation, it is assumed that "name" and "surname" are properties for the IBOutlet references to both textfields that you want to swap.  If this is the case, as long as you have "retain" for both of these properties, that will take care of the memory management (as long as you release these in the dealloc method in the .m file).

Comment: That's not true: the `text` property of an UITextField **is** in "retain", but the NSString hold by name.text will be released when you set `name.text = surname.text` (and replaced by `surname.text`). At this stage, the original `NSString` you stored in `tempString` is then not retained by anybody so will potentially be removed from memory. You need to do an explicit retain on tempString (which is a local variable and **not** a property that retains its values) during the swapping and release it afterwards. (If you're very lucky it may not crash, but you can't rely on luck!)

Comment: Your absolutely right, updated code to use an autoreleased NSString to hold what is in name.text.  Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Ok. Note that you should prefer explicitely sending retain+autorelease instead of creating a new (autoreleased) NSString, as this will avoid useless memory allocation. In practice, NSString is internally optimized to do Copy-On-Write (but you should need to be aware of that and suppose this when you code) so I think this won't really do any allocation as Cocoa is optimized for such cases, but using retain+autorelease makes more sense as you are working on the same object instead of encapsulate it in a new one ;)

Comment: Agreed, just wanted to provide a different answer than one you already provided =)